# LinqToSQL Design Query / Worry

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, linq-to-sql

I wonder if somebody could point me in the right direction. I've recently  started playing with LinqToSQL and love the strongly typed data objects etc.

I'm just struggling to understand the impact on database performance etc. For example, say I was developing a simple user profile page. The page shows basic information about the user, some information on their recent activity, and a list of unread notifications.

If I was developing a stored procedure for this page, I could create a single SP which returns multiple datatables covering all of the required information - resulting in a single db call.

However, using LinqToSQL, this could results in many calls - one for user info, atleast one for activity, atleast one for notifications, if I then want further info on notifications this may result in further calls - multiple db calls.

Should I be worried about the number of db calls happenning as a result of using this design pattern? Ie, are the multiple db handshakes etc going to degrade my db etc?

I'd appreciate your thoughts on this!

Thanks
David

Comment: I don't know about Linq to SQL - I know more about Linq to Entities. Ideally any ORM style system should cache calls so you only call out to the DB when you need to, and make as few trips as possible. Though of course it would be up to you to write your server-side implementation to take advantage of this batching, rather than *forcing* the ORM to split up your calls (e.g. use only one repository/context for the entire request, and take full advantage of `IEnumerable` deferment, rather than calling a bunch of functions that create and destroy the context, and calling `ToList` all the time).

Comment: They should also take advantage of connection pooling, so even if you "close the connection", you really just return it to the pool.  Again, Linq to Entities does this, and I don't know if Linq to SQL does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework VS LINQ to SQL VS ADO.NET with stored procedures?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698151/entity-framework-vs-linq-to-sql-vs-ado-net-with-stored-procedures)

Comment: I am wondering the exact same thing, to test this I have created a simple page with two methods, one calls a Linq query the other a SQL stored procedure, at the time these methods finish they will have performed exactly the same operation, a timer fires when the method starts and stops when it ends then the results get printed onto the screen, you may wish to try something similar to test which approach works best for you. I would post my results but It's just a side project and isnt finished yet sadly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ to SQL can consume multiple results from a stored proc if you need to go that route. Unfortnately the designer has problems mapping them correctly, so you will probably need to create your mapping manually. See http://www.thinqlinq.com/Default/Using-LINQ-to-SQL-to-return-Multiple-Results.aspx.

You can configure LINQ to SQL to eagerly load the child records if you know that you're going to need them for every parent record. Use the DataLoadOptions and .LoadWith to configure it.

You can also project an object graph with multiple child collections in the Select clause of a LINQ query to reduce the number of DB hits that you make.

Ultimately, you need to check a number of options to determine which route is the best performance for your situation. It's not a one size fits all scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Is it worst from a performance standpoint ? Yes, it should be. Multiple roundtrips are usually worse than single.

The real question is, do you mind? Is your application going to receive enough visits to warrant the added complexity of a stored procedure? Or do you value the simplicity of future modifications over raw performance?

In any case, if you need the performance, you can create a stored procedure and map it on your context. This will give you one single call, but return the data as objects 
Here is an article explaining a bit about that option: 
[linq-to-sql-returning-multiple-result-sets](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swiss_dpe_team/archive/2008/02/04/linq-to-sql-returning-multiple-result-sets.aspx)