# How to edit the sql query that Entity framework generated?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on `Visual studio 2012 (C#)` and use `Entity Framework` to handle a queries with `SQL server`.

For performance reasons I want to be able to **edit the background sql query code and customize it**. (to make entity framework more manually and to control what it produce in the back) .

I saw all the posts about `TraceToString` this is not what I mean, I need to be able to edit the background code online and not only show that.

EDIT

```
if ((activityBox.Text != "") && (biasBox.Text == ""))
{
aggGk = (from sk in db.DIM_COV_TEST_AGGREGATION_KEY 
where activityGk.Contains(sk.COV_ACTIVITY_GK) && (sk.DATE_ID >= beginTime) 
&& (sk.DATE_ID <= endTime) 
select sk.TEST_AGGREGATION_KEY_GK).Distinct().ToList(); 
}
```

Comment: for instance:
  if ((activityBox.Text != "") && (biasBox.Text == ""))
                {
                    aggGk = (from sk in db.DIM_COV_TEST_AGGREGATION_KEY
                             where activityGk.Contains(sk.COV_ACTIVITY_GK) && (sk.DATE_ID >= beginTime) && (sk.DATE_ID <= endTime)
                             select sk.TEST_AGGREGATION_KEY_GK).Distinct().ToList();
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that using if you are not compromised with the performance, you need to follow the TSQL queries. If you are a .NET developer, you will be familiarized with SQL queries.

The below link gives a greater comparision of different options

1. [Entity Framework VS LINQ to SQL VS ADO.NET with stored procedures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698151/entity-framework-vs-linq-to-sql-vs-ado-net-with-stored-procedures)

Its is also possible to use your Stored procedures with EF.
Check these two links

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx
2. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/522611/Entity-Framework-CRUD-Operations-Using-Stored-Proc

We cannot control the execution of EF queries , but surely we can do optimization of SQL queries for better performance. All things you need is to generate a model/ entity classes to handle the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can't (easily) affect the SQL generated by the framework, what you're looking for is probably [Entity SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399560.aspx) (possibly in combination with [ObjectQuery<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345303.aspx)) which let you write your own queries on top of Entity Framework in a much more flexible way.

Answer (score 0):

For some specified query that you want to customize, you can try `DataContext.ExecuteQuery<TResult>(string query, params object[] parameters)`.
But if you find there's too much you need to customize, it means that it's not a good idea to use Entify Framework in your scenario.

Answer (score -1):

From the top of my head I would say it is not possible. The entire point of having a OR framework is to avoid getting into the SQL language.

For more fruitful discussion it would be great if you share what kind of optimization you want to be done by editing the generated SQL alongwith the entities involved.

I would like to Add the following link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399560.aspx

This is not exactly editing a SQL generated from the Framework, but you could use this where you need some performance tweaking.