# VB: Object "inaccessible due to its protection level" (Visual Studio 2012)

Tags: vb.net, object, public

I'm having problems with this `SearchButton` code in VB (Visual Studio 2012):

This code in Form1.VB:

```
Private Sub SearchButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchButton.Click 
    Dim results As Artist 
    results = Array.SearchArray(artistArray(), SearchTextBox.Text) 
End Sub
```

and I'm getting an error that `artistArray` is inaccessible due to its protection level.

I'm new to VB, so I'm sure it's something I'm doing wrong, but I can't find it.

I have checked spelling, visibility (`Public`), and so on.

array.vb at the moment:

```
Public Class Array 
    Public artistArray() As Artist 
    Public searchResults(artistArray.Length) As Artist 
    Dim searchString As String 

    Public Function SearchArray(ByVal artistArray(), searchString) As Artist() 
        Dim x As Integer ' artist index variable for loop 
        Dim index As Integer = 0 ' index for results 
        For x = 0 To artistArray.GetUpperBound(0) 
            Dim temp As Artist = artistArray(x) 
            If temp.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower()) Then 
                searchResults(index) = artistArray(x) ' if search hit then add current item to result array 
                index += 1 ' and incr. result index 
            End If 
         Next 
         ReDim Preserve searchResults(index) 
         Return searchResults 
    End Function 

    ' ...
End Class
```

Comment: The code you've written doesn't make sense. There is no method `SearchArray` on the `Array` class. If you are trying to write an extension method, then this isn't correct either.

Comment: It could be because 'Public artistArray() As Artist' is in array.vb, have you tried doing:
results = Array.SearchArray(array.artistArray(), SearchTextBox.Text)

Comment: Is there a conflict between `System.Array` and your `Array`? Try renaming your class to be more descriptive of what it holds. Example: `Class ArtistArray Inherits Collection(Of Artist)`

Comment: Since `SearchArray` is not static, so your `Array.SearchArray(...)` will cause a compiling error---you sure the code is OK?  BTW. the name "Array" of the class is a bad idea

Comment: You function returns `Artist()` and you are assigning the result to a type `Artist`. Notice the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Public` is not the same as global.  In fact, VB.NET doesn't even support `Global` variables, in the strict old VB6 sense.  Even though it's `Public`, it's still scoped to the `Array` class, so you have to access if as a property of that class.  However, it's also an instance property, which means it's a member of each `Array` object (i.e. instance), not of the class, itself, for instance:

```
Dim first As Artist = Array.artistArray(0)  ' Does not work
```

But:

```
Dim a As New Array()
Dim first As Artist = a.artistArray(0)  ' Works
```

If you want to make it a shared property, meaning it will be a member of the class, itself, rather than each instance of that class, and therefore, effectively global, you need to add the `Shared` keyword, like this:

```
Public Class Array
    Public Shared arrayArtist() As Artist
    ' ...
End Class
```

Then, you will be able to access it from anywhere in your project, like this:

```
Dim first As Artist = Array.artistArray(0)  ' Works now
```

Of course, having global variables is almost always a bad design decision, but that's another topic.

All of this is a bit confusing too, because you are calling your class `Array`.  Technically, you can do that if you really want to, but I wouldn't advise it since the .NET Framework already includes a class called `Array` which is pretty fundamental.

Also, there's no reason to store the search results in a field of the class.  It would be far better if that was scoped to be local to the search method.  And it would be simpler if you used a `For Each` loop and a `List`, like this:

```
Public Class ArtistBusiness
    Public Shared Artists() As Artist

    Public Shared Function SearchArtists(artists() As Artist, searchString As String) As Artist()
        Dim results As New List(Of Artist)()
        For Each i As Artist In artists
            If i.Name.IndexOf(searchString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >=0 Then
                results.Add(i)
            End If
        Next
        Return results.ToArray()
    End Function
End Class
```

Then, you could call it like this:

```
Private Sub SearchButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchButton.Click 
    Dim results() As Artist 
    results = ArtistBusiness.SearchArtists(ArtistBusiness.Artists, SearchTextBox.Text) 
End Sub
```

It pains me to even put globals in my example, but there it is.  Notice I changed the `ToLower.Contains` to `IndexOf`, since that is safer, given certain culture issues.  I also changed the `results` variable in the click event handler to an array, since that is what the method is returning.

You can also simplify the code even more by using LINQ, like this:

```
Public Shared Function SearchArtists(artists() As Artist, searchString As String) As Artist()
    artists.Select(Function(x) x.Name.IndexOf(searchString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0).ToArray()
End Function
```

But I would advise you to spend more time learning the fundamentals before you start trying to do anything fancy, like that.

Comment: Thanks for the very clear explanation.   I am working on learning the fundamentals of VB now, and the prof wants this done a certain way.   I’ll build off your suggestions and let you know what I come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Your whole code can be replaced by a single `LINQ` line

```
Public artists As Artist()

Public Function FindArtists(searchString As String) As Artist()
    Return artists.Where(Function(a) a.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchString)).ToArray()
End Function
```

Comment: in 2013 this answer might have been OK, but I think LINQ is dying and or dead.

Comment: That is an opinion. I think a lot of people still use LINQ as there isn't a newer technology yet in the C# wold yet.

Comment: Right, nothing dies, but things do fade away. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698151/entity-framework-vs-linq-to-sql-vs-ado-net-with-stored-procedures?rq=1)