# Using variables from aspx.vb(behind code) to aspx file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to pass lvsession from the codebehind to aspx file. It keeps telling me is not declared or inaccessible due to its protection level. I've tried making it a Public variable at the class level and still no luck. I am really new to asp.net so thanks in advance.

Default.aspx

```
   <object xmlns: id="viewer" classid="clsid:d4290153-c4b5-4c27-9d66-44e94d6b0c32"
   codebase="" height="700" name="viewer" width="800">
   <param name="ServiceHandlerURL" value="" />
   <param name="SessionID" value="<%lvsession%>" />
   <param name="DocumentID" value="180484" /> 
   </object>
</body>

</asp:Content>
```

Default.aspx.vb

```
Public Class WebForm1
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Public Property lvsession As String

Public Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim authProps As OnBaseAuthenticationProperties = Hyland.Unity.Application.CreateOnBaseAuthenticationProperties("https://test.com/", "Manager", "password", "Test")
    Dim app As Hyland.Unity.Application = Hyland.Unity.Application.Connect(authProps)



    lvsession = app.SessionID
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Sorry saw other questions out there using that format

Comment: When I see them, the format will be gone.

Comment: What is lvsession? Show an example of how you tried to declare it private to the class.

Comment: I want use the lvsession from the Page_Load Sub as the variable <%=lvsession%> in Default.aspx

Comment: I want to use the value from lvsession on page load in default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Update: When I use `<%lvsession%>` it returns me error and when I use this format it returns me the desired value. `<%: lvsession %>`

```
Public Property lvsession As String
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    lvsession = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString()
End Sub
```

So I don't think the problem is related to lvsession unless it works in `<%: lvsession %>` format.

Can you try :

```
Dim app As New Hyland.Unity.Application
app.Connect(authProps)
```

And thank you [@mason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1139830/mason) for your suggestion. Bu my answer was suggesting to create an instance and I think it was clear even if it is short:

<s>I suppose you should create an instance of your lvsession</s>

please see [this answer][2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20426960/306921)

Comment: You should provide more detail, rather than leaving it all up to the link to explain. Otherwise, flag the question as a duplicate if the answer you linked to sufficiently explains how to resolve the issue.