# Conversion error (nvarchar to int) for SQL query using MVC4

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This code I received from another stackoverflow post from Agent Shark and changed it slightly for my use. Problem is I get an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '39432,39431,39430,39429,39428' to data type int.

Question is, how do I fix this problem?

The original StackOverFlow Post:

[What is the best method to access a large database using MVC 4 and Entity Framework 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23551625/what-is-the-best-method-to-access-a-large-database-using-mvc-4-and-entity-framew/23551787?noredirect=1#comment36167787_23551787)

Here is the code I'm using:

```
public void DeleteBatchCampaignContacts(IList<int> ids)
{
    if (ids == null) return;
    if (ids.Count == 0) return;

    var idsToDelete = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var id in ids)
    {
        idsToDelete.AppendFormat(",{0}", id);
    }

    db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM EmailContactCampaign WHERE EmailContact_EmailContactId in (@contactIds)",
    new SqlParameter("@contactIds", idsToDelete.ToString().Remove(0, 1)));
}
```

Comment: You must use `table-valued parameter` in conjunction with `SqlDbType.Structured`.

Comment: I'm new to writing queries.  Could you give me an example?

Comment: @Hamlet gave you two great **keywords** to use for (re)searching a solution to your problem! Just go and google and then read, learn and apply what you've learned ....

Comment: I'm fully agree with @marc_s ;)

Comment: OK, I 've got my homework.  Thanks for the the helping hand. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(string.Format("DELETE FROM CampainContacts WHERE CampaignId in ({0})", idsToDelete.ToString().Remove(0, 1)));
```