# Performance comparision between Entity Framework, ADO.Net and L2S

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, ado.net

I am about to start a project in .Net which will work on huge amount of data (about 700-800 GB, possibly more) stored in SQL Server 2008. I need to decide what to use for data access from among **Entity Framework**, **ADO.Net** and **LinQ to SQL**. I have to quantify the performance which I have no clue how to go about.

Suppose if I were to perform CRUD operations on the DB tables taking millions of rows at a time, how can I note the time taken and other performance factors(if any) in all the three cases ?

Can you please guide me how do I quantify the performance so that I can compare all the above and use whichever suits me?

**N.B**:I have read posts suggesting the benefits and disadvantages of each of them. But I want to be sure whether or not there exists a way to put the comparisions in numeric terms.

Comment: Have you check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698151/entity-framework-vs-linq-to-sql-vs-ado-net-with-stored-procedures)?

Comment: Its a nice post. Explains everything that I want. Thanks.