# Should SQL Server transaction tables always have a surrogate primary key

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-design

For a large table of transactions (100 million rows, 20 GB) that already has a primary key (a natural composite key of 4 columns), will it help performance to add an identity column and make that the primary key?

The current primary key (the natural composite primary key of 4 columns) does the job, but I have been told that you should always have a surrogate key. **So, could improve performance by creating an identity column and making that the primary key?**

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

EDIT: This transaction table is mainly joined to definition tables and used to populate reports.

EDIT: If I did add a surrogate key, it wouldn't be used in any joins. The existing key fields would be used.

EDIT: There would be no child tables to this table

Comment: This is an "it depends" type of question. What are you doing with the transaction data after you load it? Do you ever need to join individual rows against metadata or other transaction tables? Or do you mostly use the transaction data in aggregate form? Do you have rows in other tables that relate? The identity column would really only help in joins - it is going to *decrease* your write performance to the table as well as space to a minor extent.

Comment: @Aaron: +1 - "The identity column would really only help in joins".

Comment: @Yuck: one other potential use case would be if the application recording the transactions were to log something elsewhere else - it could use the SCOPE_IDENTITY() value instead of the wider natural key, and this would in turn make it easier to come back and identify the row in question should an investigation result. But on its own this doesn't seem to be the kind of thing that would tip the scales in favor of adding a surrogate.

Comment: @Aaron: By default I design all tables to use an `int` or `bigint` `IDENTITY` column as a surrogate primary key with a clustered index. There have been a lot of articles written to support this. There are certainly reasons **not** to do this, but for most OLTP solutions it is a reasonable starting point.

Comment: I think it is often used as a blanket, "every table needs this" knee-jerk reaction. Creating a new table? Better put an identity column on it. I think this can be misguided. YMMV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if:

- you have child tables that are larger
- you have nonclustered indexes

In each of these cases, the PK (assumed clustered) of your table will be in each child entry/NC entry. So making the clustered key narrower will benefit.

If you have just non NC indexes (maybe one) and no child tables all you'll achieve is

- a wider row (more data pages used)
- a slightly smaller B-tree (which is a fraction of total space)

...but you'll still need an index/constraint on the current 4 columns anyway = an increase in space.

If your 4 way key capture parent table keys too (sounds likely) then you'd lose the advantage of overlap. This would be covered by the new index/constraint though.

So no, you probably don't want to do it.

We threw away a surrogate key (bigint) on a billion+ row table and moved to the actual 11-way key and reduced space on disk by 65%+ because of a simpler structure (one less index, slighty more rows per page etc)

Comment: Thanks for that. The info on the billion+ row table was helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Just adding an IDENTITY column and adding a new constraint and index for it is very unlikely to improve performance. The table will be larger and therefore scans and seeks could take longer. There will also be more indexes to update. Of course it all depends what you are measuring the performance of... and whether you intend to make other changes to code or database when you add the new column. Adding an IDENTITY column and doing nothing else would probably be unwise.

Answer (score 2):

Given your edits, and all the conversation the question has sparked notwithstanding, I would suggest that adding an IDENTITY column to this table will create a lot more harm than benefit.

Answer (score 1):

**---EDIT:**
Based on the edits to the question, adding an identity/surrogate key might not be the solution to this problem.

**--Original Answer.**

One case of performance improvement would be when you use joins and when you have child tables.

In the absence of surrogate keys, you would have to replicate all th4 4 keys to the child table and join on the 4 columns.

```
t_parent
-------------
col1,
col2,
col3,
col4,
col5,
constraint pk_t_parent primary key (col1,col2,col3,col4)

t_child
----------
col1,
col2,
col3,
col4,
col7,
col8,
constraint pk_t_child primary key (col1,col2,col3,col4, col5),
constraint fk_parent_child foreign key (col1, col2, col3, col4) references
                                 t_parent ((col1, col2, col3, col4))
```

The joins will include all the 4 columns..

```
select t2.*
  from t_parent t1, t_child t2
  where (t1.col1 = t2.col1 and 
         t1.col2 = t2.col2 and 
         t1.col3 = t2.col3 and 
         t1.col4 = t2.col4
        )
```

If you use a surrogate key and create a unique constraint on the 4 columns (which are now part of the primary key), it will be both efficient and the data would still be validated as before.

Comment: While that's true, I've found that often the very information you need is carried in the composite key. When that happens, you don't need the join in the first place--the information you need is already in the referencing table. (This happens a lot more often than I thought it would.)

Comment: I agree. But, if you have child/dependent tables 3-4 levels deep, the primary key for tables down the hierarchy would have way too many columns than is necessary. There might be joins at some point, if not right away. And most of all, I think it would be consistent to have the surrogate keys instead of changing the table design when needed (or when you might need joins later on)

Comment: I would expect a 100m row table is the lowest level. Your case doesn't add up: increase size on this table to save space in a child table that probably isn't there if it was, it'd be a very special case (eg very narrow or for a subset only) and the size increase in the 100m parent will more than offset the benefits of a child table. Update: OP now says no child table

Comment: @gbn- I am not proposing this to save space on the child table(s). May be 100 million rows is the lowest level table and it will never need any more child tables, but isn't it an arbitrary number to make this decision on? How do we know for sure which one is the lowest level table in other cases?

Comment: @Rajesh Charmarthi: if I had referencing tables 4 levels deep, I'd expect the primary key for tables at every level to have exactly the number of columns that is necessary. And `CREATE VIEW` is your friend.

Comment: @gbn - Based on the OP's edits, I agree that changing his model to use surrogate key might not give him any performance improvement. Thanks for the discussion though. I am still trying to understand how getting rid of the surrogate key lead to a 65%+ decrease in disk space. Isn't the space for the key (Key Data and the Key index) very small compared to the actual row length (data)?

Comment: We removed the NC index that enforced the natural key when we made it clustered. The surrogate was clustered before.

Answer (score 1):

One place where performance is hurt is on the change of the data in the natural key. The change woudl then have to promulgate to all the child records. For instance, suppose one of those fields was company name and the company changed their name, then all the related records, and there could be millions of them, would have to change but if you used a surrogate key, only one record would have to change. Integer joins tend to be faster (generally much faster than 4 column joins) and wrting the code to join is generally faster as well. However, on the other hand, having the vital four fields may mean the join isn't needed as often. Insert performanc ewilltake a slight hit as well as the surrogate key has to be generated and indexed. Usually this is so small a hit as to be unnoticalbe but the possibility is there.

A four column natural key is often not a unique as you think it will be because that number of columns the data tends to change over time. While it is unique now, will it be unique over time? If you have used a surrogate key and a unique index onteh natural key and it turns out later not to unique, then all you have to do is drop the unique index. If it is the PK and there are child tables, you have to totally redesign your database.

Only you can decide which if any of these considerations affects your specific data needs, surrogate keys are better for some applications and worse for others.